# Diseño de experimentos en r

Tags: r

Tengo la base de datos de un experimento en el cual tengo decir cuales son los factores que mas contribuyen  que un pancake sea esponjoso. Alguien sabe hacer el codigo en r?

Comment: Bienvenida Camila a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y creo que también fuera de la temática ya que trata más sobre estadística que sobre programación.

Comment: Deberías indicar que tipo de datos es la respuesta que mide el "grado de esponjosidad" (numérico, categórico ordinal, etc) y que variables o factores quieres estudiar. Dependiendo de esto es el modelo (lineal, no lineal, lineal generalizado, etc, de efectos fijos, aleatorios, mixtos, etc.). Y de acuerdo al modelo, el código a utilizar.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822